# Trigonometry questions please help

Tags: trigonometry

Given triangle $FGH$ with $\angle F=75°$, 
$\angle G=20°$ and $GF=23$, what is the length of $GH$?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend finding angle H using the fact that the interior angle measures of a triangle add up to 180, then applying the Law of Sines: $\frac{\sin(\angle H)}{FG} = \frac{\sin(\angle G)}{GH}$. You should be able to plug in your values for the measures of angle H, angle G, and side FG, then solve for the length of GH.